# Capture a part of application and save it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

In my app i want to **capturea** a part of my android application **UI** and save it programmatically .

For example i want do this actions :

1. In `Activity/Fragment` user clicks one `Button` .
2. **capture** from a part of `Layout` for example a `LinearLayout` that have `id="captureMe"` .
3. **Save** captured image somewhere .

how i can  implement it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use this function just pass your view object

```
public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Then Save this file

```
    public void saveImage(Bitmap inImage) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File mydir = new File(root + "/demo/");
    mydir.mkdirs();

    String fname = "Image.jpeg";

    File file = new File (mydir, fname);
    String path2=file.getPath();
    Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(file);

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);


        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, hope it works

```
LinearLayout captureMe = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.captureMe);
captureMe.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
captureMe.buildDrawingCache();

bitmap = captureMe.getDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 1):

First Use this function to get bitmap of view that you want to capture:

```
public static Bitmap getViewBitmap(View v, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, 
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
    Canvas c = new Canvas(viewBitmap);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return viewBitmap;
}
```

Then use this code to save this bitmap to storage:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream fOutputStream = null;
File file = new File(path + "/Captures/", "screen.jpg");
try {
    fOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    capturedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOutputStream);
    fOutputStream.flush();
    fOutputStream.close();
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),   
    file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Save Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Save Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```